# How can I plot these 3 functions within the range(-4,4) with 0.01 stepsize?

Tags: function, plot, graph, scilab

function[]=PieceWise1(x)

```
if x<=0 then
    root=sqrt(4-(x+2)^2)
    y1=2+root
    disp(y1)
elseif x>0
    y1=-0.5*x
    disp(y1)
end
```

endfunction

function[]=PieceWise2(x)

```
if x<=0 then
    root=sqrt(4-(x+2)^2)
    y2=2-root
    disp(y2)
elseif x>0
    y2=0.5*x-4
    disp(y2)
end
```

endfunction

function[]=PieceWise3(x)

```
if x<-0.12 then
    y3=-4-(x^-1)/2
    disp(y3)
elseif x>=0
    z=x-2*int(x/2)
    y3=4*(1-z)^2
    disp(y3)
else
    disp(0)
end
```

endfunction

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your function must return a value

Comment: function y1=PieceWise1(x)
         if x<=0 then
            r=sqrt(4-(x+2)^2)
            y1=2+r
       else x>0
           y1=-0.5*x
        end
        endfunction

Answer (score 0):

```
   function y1=PieceWise1(x)
     if x<=0 then
        r=sqrt(4-(x+2)^2)
        y1=2+r
      else x>0
       y1=-0.5*x
      end
   endfunction
```

then you evaluate these functions using the feval function

```
  Y1=feval(linspace(-4,4,100),PieceWise1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function r = PieceWise1(x)
    r = -0.5*x
    s = x<=0
    if or(s), r(s) = 2 + sqrt(4-(x(s)+2).^2), end // .^ instead of ^
endfunction

function r = PieceWise2(x)
    r = 0.5*x - 4
    s = x<=0
    if or(s), r(s) = 2 - sqrt(4-(x(s)+2).^2), end
endfunction

function r = PieceWise3(x)
    r = zeros(x)
    s = x<-0.12
    if or(s), r(s) = -4 - 1./x(s)/2, end  // ./ instead of /
    s = x>=0
    if or(s), r(s) = 4*(1- x(s) + 2*int(x(s)/2)).^2, end
endfunction

x = (-4:0.01:4)';
clf
plot(x,PieceWise1, x,PieceWise2, x,PieceWise3)
```

[image]